# JavaScript event execute immediately after bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to immediately execute an event after I bind it.  For example:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    alert("Some code");
});
```

Typically what I've done in the past is:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(resizeFunc);
    resizeFunc(); //This will execute immediately
});

function resizeFunc() {
    alert("Some code");
}
```

But that is not helpful for anonymous functions, and it is a bit verbose.  I'd like to do something like: `$(window).resize(function () {})();` or `$(window).resize(function () {}).trigger();` but those don't work.

Is there a way to immediately execute anonymous functions on bind?

Comment: You need to trigger the specific event `.trigger('resize')`.

Comment: You can use a callback, but I don't really understand what result you want to achieve

Comment: Thank you, Heretic.  That was the exact answer!  Regarding the duplicate, I did many searches and couldn't find where this was answered (though I was surprised).